# Material UI list component doesn't show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, material-ui

I want to display a Material UI list as part of my drop down menu (a Material UI drawer component) for mobile view but for some reason the actual list doesn't get displayed.

The code for the list looks like this:

```
const menuItems = [
    {
       text: 'Home',
       path: '/'
    },
    {
       text: 'About',
       path: '/about'
    }
];

...

<List>
    {menuItems.map(item => (
        <ListItem
             button
             key={item.text}
             onClick={() => history.push(item.path)}
        >
             <ListItemText>{item.text}</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
    ))}
</List>
```

This is the result where my list items should be displayed but instead I get this strange icon:

[image: Result]

[image]

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "firebase": "^8.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-timeago": "^6.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

--

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-glitter-tcpmi?file=/src/App.js) is a working CodeSandbox example

Comment: Can you please share a small working code snippet on codesandbox.io or something?

Comment: I added a working example please have a look at the edit at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the import.

Correct:

```js
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
```

Answer (score 2):

You imported `List` from `"@material-ui/icons/List"`. You should remove it and import `List` from `"@material-ui/core"`:

```
import { List } from "@material-ui/core";
```

[image: Edit floral-snowflake-ub04r]